# My network profile is showing as private instead of domain profile after installing Active Directory DNS on Windows Server 2019 VMware Workstation

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, vmware-workstation, window-server-2019

After installing Active Directory and DNS role on VMware Workstation with domain "mylab.local". I used NAT switch on my VM and my IpV4 settings are

[image]

After installation my current network profile was showing as mylab.local
[image]

However after restarting my VM my network profile changes to private and Domain profile is not available to switch.

[image]

```
> Get-NetConnectionProfile
Name             : Network
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet0
InterfaceIndex   : 14
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Several users have reported this problem with Windows Server 2019
Some links to the solution are
[Solution from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/400385/network-location-awareness-not-detecting-domain-ne.html)

First check if restarting the Network Location Awareness service fixes the issue?.
[image]

If `yes` then for permanen fix I followed the suggestion and made below registry change to my Server 2019
we need to add this registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters
>
> Add a DWORD parameter :AlwaysExpectDomainController
>
> Set value to:1

Note: This registry key alters the behavior when NLA retries domain detection.

[image]

It fixed the problem for me!